# Get On sale product collection in magento 2

Tags: magento2, special-price

I want to show all the on sale product on one page.
Can any one help me with the code to get the products collection which are on Sale i.e which has special price assigned in magento 2

This is my block code

```
<?php

 namespace Vidushi\Contact\Block;

 use Zend_Db_Expr;

 class OnSaleProduct extends AbstractSlider
   {
     /**
       * @inheritdoc
    */
  public function getProductCollection()
  {
      $visibleProducts = $this->_catalogProductVisibility- 
     >getVisibleInCatalogIds();
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()- 
>setVisibility($visibleProducts);
    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
            'special_from_date',
            ['date' => true, 'to' => $this->getEndOfDayDate()],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'special_to_date',
            ['or' => [0 => ['date' => true,
                                               'from' => $this- 
  >getStartOfDayDate()],
                                         1 => ['is' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                                             'null'
                                         )],]],
            'left'
        )->addAttributeToSort(
            'news_from_date',
            'desc'
        );
    return $collection;
}
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Zend_Db_Expr;

class OnSaleProduct extends AbstractSlider
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $visibleProducts = $this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->setVisibility($visibleProducts);
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'special_from_date',
                ['date' => true, 'to' => $this->getEndOfDayDate()],
                'left'
            )->addAttributeToFilter(
                'special_to_date',
                ['or' => [0 => ['date' => true,
                                                   'from' => $this->getStartOfDayDate()],
                                             1 => ['is' => new Zend_Db_Expr(
                                                 'null'
                                             )],]],
                'left'
            )->addAttributeToSort(
                'news_from_date',
                'desc'
            );
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but its not working

Comment: any error ??????

Comment: Error filtering template: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/auto1/public_html/app/code/Vidushi/Contact/view/frontend/templates/list.phtml on line 4

Comment: Collection is coming empty i gueess

Comment: please attach your code

Comment: <?php
$collection = $block->getProductCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}

Comment: this is from phtml file

Comment: please attach getProductCollection() function code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118005/discussion-between-nafsss-and-rk-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;
use Zend_Db_Expr;

class OnSaleProduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
   protected $_catalogProductVisibility;
   protected $_productCollectionFactory;

   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $productVisibility;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $visibleProducts = $this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds();
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->setVisibility($visibleProducts);
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                'special_from_date',
                ['date' => true, 'to' => $this->getEndOfDayDate()],
                'left'
            )->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date',
                ['or' => [0 => ['date' => true,
                'from' => $this->getStartOfDayDate()],
                 1 => ['is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')],]],
                'left'
            )->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date','desc'
            )->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())->setPageSize(
                $this->getProductsCount()
            );
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below solution,**

```
<?php

namespace Vidushi\Contact\Block;

class OnSaleProduct  extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $productVisibility;
    protected $productStatus;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $price_from=""; //add here the starting date
        $price_to = ""; //add here the ending date
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s >= %s', ['special_price', $price_from])
            ->addPriceDataFieldFilter('%s <= %s', ['special_price', $price_to])
            ->addSpecialPrice()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
            ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
            ->setPageSize(5);

            return $collection;

    }
}
```